# Is rosdoc exist in electric?

Tags: ros, rosdoc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found when I run rosdoc, it shows:

```
 sam@sam:~/code/ros/topic/basic_topic$ rosdoc
 rosdoc: command not found
 sam@sam:~/code/ros/topic/basic_topic$
```

Should I install rosdoc from source?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29010/is-rosdoc-exist-in-electric?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on diamondback, and there I usually run rosdoc with `rosrun rosdoc rosdoc`, since rosdoc itself is not in the path the way rosmake etc. is. I hope this applies for electric as well.

---

Originally posted by [Chris L](https://answers.ros.org/users/1645/chris-l/) with karma: 61 on 2012-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-03-03**:
It does.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-03-03**:
You also need to install the "documentation" stack, e.g. "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-documentation"